# calculate percentange from data of two rows with different select conditions

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a table that shows the state of tasks of a project, when the task is finished the state = 1 when the task is not finished the state = 0 by default

```sql
create tasks(
  id int primary key identitiy(1, 1),
  p_id int references projects(id),
  emp_id int references users(id),
  state int default (0)
)
```

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of completed tasks by dividing the `select count(state) from tasks where p_id = 2` over `select count(state) from tasks where p_id = 2 AND state = 0` and multiplying the result by 100 but I can't get the query to work.

I tried a number of solutions I found but I couldn't find a question that had the same conditions on the select statements.

I'm trying to get the result into a java program through JDBC and tried to include `allowMultiQueries=true` to the connectionURL or use two different query statements and nesting the ResultSets but nothing worked so far

(Edit) this is the method I'm working with in java, when I run it with `p_id = 2` it throws the exception `The result set is closed`

```
public void projectProgress()throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    SqlConnection DB = new SqlConnection(); 
    int id = Integer.parseInt(PMprogressFrame.Pnum.getText());
    String sql = "select count(state) as finishedTasks from tasks where P_id = "+id+" AND state = 1";
    String sql2 = "select count(state) as totalTasks from tasks where p_id = 2";
    
    ResultSet result = DB.st.executeQuery(sql);
    ResultSet result2 = DB.st.executeQuery(sql2);
    while(result.next()){
        while(result2.next()){

        float var1 = result.getFloat("finishedTasks");
        float var2 = result.getFloat("totalTasks");
        float p = (var1/var2)*100;
        PMprogressFrame.progress.setText(p+"%");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my connection method:

```
public class SqlConnection {

    Connection conn;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    public SqlConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://MEMENTOMORI:1433;databaseName=PMS;user=sa;password=12345;encrypt=false;allowMultiQueries=true";  
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        st = conn.createStatement();
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you run the two queries after each other, store both results in Java and calculate the percentage there? Or is it mandatory to get the result directly via SQL?

Comment: @deHaar it would be fine if I could store them in java and make the calculation there, I tired doing that by making a second query statement in a couple of different ways but it says the result set is closed.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be a different problem… If the `ResultSet` is closed already, you have closed it or it was automatically closed. Do you use a `try` statement? Please [edit] your question and include the relevant Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation would be the simplest method here. You could do this with a `SUM` divided by a `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE state WHEN 0 THEN 1. ELSE 0. END) / NULLIF(COUNT(state),0)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE p_id = 2;
```

The `NULLIF` is there to avoid divide by zero errors.

However, `AVG` might actually be an easier solution:

```sql
SELECT AVG(CASE state WHEN 0 THEN 1. ELSE 0. END)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE p_id = 2;
```

Comment: Then change `WHEN 0` to `WHEN 1`, @Ahmed . Based on your description, I assumed you wanted the above, as you stated you wanted `(select count(state) from tasks where p_id = 2) / (select count(state) from tasks where p_id = 2 AND state = 0)`; For the above that would result in `4 / 1 = 4` not `0.25`

Comment: that works! sorry for the confusion and thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

you can try sql

```sql
select sum(state)/count(state) 
from tasks where p_id = 2
```